# Travis throws Code Sign error

Tags: ios, travis-ci, code-signing, provisioning-profile

▸ Check Dependencies
❌  Code Sign error: No code signing identities found: No valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair) were found.

I'm configuring Keychains in the following way:

```
security create-keychain -p travis ios-build.keychain

# Make the custom keychain default, so xcodebuild will use it for signing
security default-keychain -s ios-build.keychain

# Unlock the keychain
security unlock-keychain -p travis ios-build.keychain

# Set keychain timeout to 1 hour for long builds
security set-keychain-settings -t 3600 -l ~/Library/Keychains/ios-build.keychain

# Add certificates to keychain and allow codesign to access them
security import scripts/certs/apple.cer -k ~/Library/Keychains/ios-build.keychain -T /usr/bin/codesign
# security import scripts/certs/distribution.cer -k ~/Library/Keychains/ios-build.keychain -T /usr/bin/codesign
security import scripts/certs/distribution.p12 -k ~/Library/Keychains/ios-build.keychain -P {pass} -T /usr/bin/codesign

echo "list keychains: "
security list-keychains
echo " ****** "

echo "find indentities keychains: "
security find-identity -p codesigning  ~/Library/Keychains/ios-build.keychain
echo " ****** "

# Put the provisioning profile in place
mkdir -p ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles
cp "scripts/certs/AdHoc.mobileprovision" ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/
cp "scripts/certs/AppStore.mobileprovision" ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/
```

Have someone ideas how to fix it?

Line:

```
# security import scripts/certs/distribution.cer -k ~/Library/Keychains/ios-build.keychain -T /usr/bin/codesign
```

Doesn't affect for result.

Comment: What is the output you get from running the script? The security import command seems correct.  Are you sure the path to the .cer file is correct? Also, 1 hour for builds?

Comment: Also, if you open the Keychain Access app ad open the ios-build keychain, do you have any certs or keys?

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly working script. Problem was in another thing in Travis CI.

But it needs uncomment line:

## security import scripts/certs/distribution.cer -k ~/Library/Keychains/ios-build.keychain -T /usr/bin/codesign

Comment: In your code at the top, the line is uncommented.  Then you have a second reference to the line where it is commented.  I am still not sure what the problem was or exactly what you did to fix it.

Comment: This code works perfectly:) Problem was in other things. Thanks for trying to help me!